# Passing dynamic arrays into the argument

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

I have a class constructor accepting `params  T[][] arrays`.

```
public CartesianProduct(params  T[][] arrays)
{
}
```

I am passing the arrays below which is working fine

```
string[] arr1 = { "MSG1" };
string[] arr2 = { "OFFER1", "OFFER2" };
string[] arr3 = { "CTA1", "CTA2" };
var cross = new CartesianProduct<string>(arr1,arr2,arr3);
```

This works fine if i know the number of arrays and then pass it in the argument. The problem is when i am creating a button in the windows form to add new arrays. For example i have a simple text box and a button which creates an array. Click Add new array will create another array. How can i pass these arrays in the argument? Help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't get the last part. Please elaborate.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ In the code above i have 3 arrays which are declared in the code and this is passed as a argument but i am creating dynamic arrays using a button.And i need to pass all the dynamic arrays as a parameter

Comment: In that case, you may want to show your Button Clicking code - how you add items such that it creates new array.

Comment: @OwaisAhmed So everytime you click the button you want to add the array to the variable? in that case make it global and keep a count of the index and add to it.

Comment: I think you want to dynamically create array of different number of parameters, it works fine on 3 parameters and you want to make it on dynamically parameters?

Comment: yes you are right@user6002727

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ but how to pass that as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **not** dynamically add a 4th parameter to the call. You **can** dynamically create an array containing an arbitrary number of other arrays and pass that:

```
var aList = new List<string[]>();
aList.Add(arr1);
//...
var cross = new CartesianProduct<string>(aList.ToArray());
```

You may consider adding another constructor that accepts a List directly.